How can I imply the order of a series of messages?
The sender will send text messages that seem meaningful, like "How are you today?" and "How is the weather today?"
However, for the receiver, "How are you today?" is only meaningful if it is received in the order of "1". The problem is that the receiver might get the messages in random order.
Is there a way for the sender to mark the order of the messages without adding obvious numbers, like "How are you today?[1]"? Perhaps in a more implicit way?

Actually, protocols that need to deal with packet reordering (e.g. TCP, RTP, IPsec, DTLS) essentially do that - include a sequence number (or something equivalent) with the message.  The users of the protocol don't see it, because it's embedded in the protocol.

That I know. What I'm trying to do is: adding such seq that could only not be understood by the traffic analyzers in between. For instance I can know the seq numbers of UDP and IP easily by using wireshark.

What are you trying to hide?  If the adversary places the traffic analyzer close to the sender (before any packet reordering is likely), then he knows the sequence anyways.  BTW: UDP and IPv6 doesn't have sequence numbers.

Sender and receiver agree on a common secret. From that secret a state is derived and held within a cryptographic pseudo random number generator. When messages are constructed, they include a sequence number of say 128 bits generated by the random number generator.  As both sender and receiver generate identical sequence numbers in identical order, the messages can also be ordered as intended. A large enough (bit-wise) sequence number would also allow re-synchronisation should any messages go astray.
Any intercepted messages cannot be ordered if the evil listener does not have the common secret. Any good?

Why not just encrypt / decrypt a sequence number if there already is a shared secret? I'm not saying that this is a bad solution, but a simple sequence number seems easier to sync.

Well, the issue is how do you add such a sequence number into a normal text like "How are you today" while making it look innocent. Consider such messages would be achieved and analyzed by a powerful surveillance conductor.

If you want to hide secret communication over an insecure channel then you probably want to use steganography. Steganography offers no data protection and is in essence security through obscurity so you might also want to protect sensitive data with encryption or other cryptography before hiding it with steganography, just in case eavesdroppers figure out your steganography scheme. If you don't trust the communication channel you're on then you could first establish a shared secret in a different channel and use that to encrypt your secret data.
There are many steganography techniques available, the simplest for larger amounts of data is probably to include a file with room for random noise (maybe a photo or audio) in the message. For smaller amounts of data, such as the sequence numbers you describe, it might be easy enough to make up some rule based on the text in the message, like a character count or ascii value sum. Look up examples and try to find something that suits your need.
